# What Is Difference Between {Server Name} localhost vs .\SqlExpress

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

can you please tell me
What Is Difference Between {Server Name} (local),localhost,(pc-name)\SQLEXPRESS,.\SqlExpress ...

Answer (score 3):

Well, the instance name of your SQL Server instance is just the host name of your machine, if it's the standard instance. You can have only one standard instance per host.

Let's say your server machine has the name `srv1` and you install a Sql Server 2008 R2 on it as a standard instance. Then you can refer to it as: `srv1`, `(local)` or just `.`. The latter two names only make sense, if you connect from the `srv1` machine to the server.

If your install any other instance you must choose a named instance and the name will be appended to the hostname with a backslash inbetween, e.g. `srv1\sqlexpress`.  You can connect to it via `srv1\sqlexpress` or `.\sqlexpress`, again the latter is only possible from the machine itself.

Answer (score 0):

**(pc-name)\SQLEXPRESS,   &
        .\SqlExpress -** 
boils down to the same thing (a sql instance called SQL express), the only difference would be on which PC/network node it is located, the latter would connect to the instance on your local machine

**localhost** - would be would sql instance specified as your local instance

Comment: can you please tell me which one should i use for local pc i.e. priority order

Comment: i rate if you're just creating a quick app, localhost is fine. But in general I prefer the fully qualified name. @Mithrandir has a good explanation of the in's & the outs of why instances are named they way they are

Comment: use this one - (pc-name)\SQLEXPRESS